NSwag auto generate client: Generates return object type function wrong
Just I'm trying to generate HttpClient generated file by NSwag from my API controller.
I have this marked row in my API controller:

But it generates here wrong return type:

I'm expecting return object type:
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task<PageData<IEnumerable<ContractDto>>>GetContractAsync();

Please, can anybody give me an advice, how can I solve it?
Thank you
